# Multer: Different Storage Engines for multiple POST requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm building an app to upload files to my server, I'm using multer to save files on the server's folders. I'm trying to make my `/uploads` route catch multiple files (currently only two images) and store them in different multer Storage Engines:

**Storage Engines**

```
const serumPresetsStorageCfg = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "./src/serum-presets");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + "  --  " + file.originalname);
    },
});
const serumPresetsStorage = multer({storage: serumPresetsStorageCfg});

//**********************************************************************

const showcaseImageStorageCfg = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "./src/showcase-image");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + "  --  " + file.originalname);
    },
});
const showcaseImageStorage = multer({storage: showcaseImageStorageCfg});
```

**/uploads Route**

```
app.post("/uploads", serumPresetsStorage.single("kit-image"), (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.file);});

app.post("/uploads", showcaseImageStorage.single("showcase-image"), (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.file);});
```

`kit-image` POST request works fine, however, when I try to make a POST request using `showcase-image` key on `postman API` I get the following error:
`MulterError: Unexpected field`

I thought that specifying different keys on `.single("")` would allow me to catch different POST requests on the `/uploads` route, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

My question is... Is there a way I can get these different POST requests on `/uploads` and handle them separately with my different Storage Engines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have same endpoint name on both request, there will be issue on same endpoint with different request.

Unless you make changes on different route

```
app.post("/uploads/serum-presets", serumPresetsStorage.single("kit-image"), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);
  // Handle serum presets upload
});

app.post("/uploads/showcase-image", showcaseImageStorage.single("showcase-image"), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);
  // Handle showcase image upload
});
```

OR

Create a controller and put additional form-value in order to validate which request your plan to do. Based on form-value, you can call it separately.

```
app.post("/uploads", (req, res, next) => {
  const fieldName = req.body.fieldName; // Get the field name from the request body
  switch (fieldName) {
    case "kit-image":
      serumPresetsStorage.single(fieldName)(req, res, next);
      break;
    case "showcase-image":
      showcaseImageStorage.single(fieldName)(req, res, next);
      break;
    default:
      // Handle invalid field name
      break;
  }
}, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);
  // Handle file upload based on field name
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I know I can put different routes but I really needed to send it to the same route, because on my HTML document the Submit button sends all of my files and data using the same form with a POST request... So I would have to make multiple forms and that would look really really ugly.

Any resources for your second solution? I really want to learn more about it.

Comment: In this case, you need to work on different approach. Check after last updated answer

Comment: Thanks so much for your help this far. Your switch seems like a great idea! But unfortunately it's not working... The code gets stuck on the switch and all the `req` attributes return `undefined`.

Comment: both images upload in same time or separately?

Comment: I was planning on uploading them at the same time in the HTML document, but so far all of these tests and examples were made with single Postman API requests. But nevermind, I figure this is a Multer limitation and I'll just have to deal with it... I will likely just make separate forms and send each file to different routes like your first suggestion. It's not the cleanest way to go but at least it will work lol! Thanks so much for your help man, I would upvote your posts but I don't have enough points haha.

Comment: Alright man. Glad you have solve this issue :)